# "Error: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, use-package" when I byte compile

Tags: debugging, emacs

When I byte compiled my init.el, I got the following error message.

> ➤ emacs --batch -f batch-byte-compile init.el
>
> In toplevel form:
> init.el:12:1: Error: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, use-package

and this is my init.el.

```
(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
             '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(setq package-user-dir (expand-file-name "elpa" user-emacs-directory))
(package-initialize)
(unless package-archive-contents
  (package-refresh-contents))

(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(require 'use-package)
```

Why did I get the error? How can I fix is?

Environment Info

```
➤ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 28.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GNU Emacs comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You may redistribute copies of GNU Emacs
under the terms of the GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file named COPYING.
```

OS: macOS Big Sur

Answer (score 1):

I too am on a Mac with the same version of Emacs and was having similar problems byte-compiling my startup files. I found that during command line --batch byte compilation the load-path did not include any of the package directories. Using the following as the equivalent of your next to last init.el stanza overcame the errors that led me here, hopefully in a way that is immune to future changes.

```
(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package)
  (eval-when-compile
    (unless (bound-and-true-p package--initialized)
      (package-initialize))  ;; be sure load-path includes package directories
    (require 'use-package)
    ))
```